# Songbird looping my library playlist

Tags: itunes, libraries, songbird

I'm using Songbird (on Windows) as my iTunes replacement. There's two things that annoy me about Songbird:

1) It has a web browser built in. I can ignore this as I don't use it. But, seriously, a web browser? :/
2) It loops my library. This, I don't like.

The way I play my audio is by launching Windows Explorer, navigating to my media library and double clicking on a single MP3. I only want to hear that one MP3.

I don't use the Media Import function in Songbird - Or any other media player. But it insists on adding every song I play to the Library. Disabling this would be excellent but, falling short of that, I'd at least like to stop it repeating every song in the library.

When Songbird finishes playing the last song in the Library (which is the song I just opened via Windows Explorer (gets appended to the library)), it jumps to the top of the library and starts playing all the songs again.

How can I stop this? Songbird is set to 'Repeat none'

Comment: Which version are you using? The "looping" doesn't occur for me with v1.4.0b3. Personally, I use Windows Media Player for the odd mp3 file, and Songbird for my music collection. As for your other dislike, I agree that it is unnecessary bloat (which might be one of your reasons for switching from iTunes). But seeing as Songbird uses the same platform as Firefox, it seems natural that there is a web browser.

Comment: I downloaded it less than a week ago. So I'm guessing it's the latest version. I don't mind Windows Media Player... But I want a program to handle my iPod as well and it seems easier to just have one program do the lot

Answer (score 0):

1.4.2 is out now, and the looping it probably repeat, just turn it off, if thats it.